# Apply discount directly to subtotal in Magento

Tags: magento

Thanks in advance.

how can i deduct some discount price from subtotal in view cart page by code, actually i want to give discount on fly to the customer who is logged in and has purchased some product.

-Jitendra..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a shopping cart price rule with:

```
Customer groups: Everything except NOT LOGGED IN
Coupon code: none
Conditions:
    Product Subselection:
        Total quantity equals or greater than 1 for ANY:
         Sku = yoursku
         Sku = anothersku
Actions:
    Apply fixed amount discount
    Discount Amount: $X
```

Please let me know if that matches your situation, or clarify the conditions for the discount.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks Joe, you are right somehow but my requirement is slightly different, i want to deduct some price(discount price) from the subtotal this price will be specific for the specific user in my store, so i have decided to deduct this discount value directly from the subtotal. Right now i am working on session.php for this but not lucky if u have any solution please suggest me, if i get any solutions i ll definitely put here as i am doing always.

Answer (score 1):

its solved,

check the `setGrandTotal` in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Grand.php
```

please override this file and make any changes...

-Thanks

Jitendra Dhobi.